# How can I reduce Unity file size? (for Mobile)

Tags: unity, mobile

I looked at the file size of a project I completed for mobile platforms in Unity. The file is 1.26 GB, only the Assets file is 44.5 MB, only the library file is 1.21 GB. I want to downsize it by a significant amount. I'm not sure exactly what I can and cannot delete in the Library file, and I don't know if this will work.

What are the things that I should definitely not delete in the Unity/Library file for mobile platforms, what can I delete...?

Comment: Did you check out our [past questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+build+size) about this?

Comment: It would be easier to tell you what you can delete, rather than what you can't.